Proving that subtraction with an in-band error value only returns the error value when there's an actual error
I have a function called flip_coordinate. I tried chipping away at How can this code about square matrices be fixed? and trying to make progress on some of the admitted lemmas, but after maybe an hour or so I gave up and tried something easier.
Right now, I am interested in a simple function that flips a coordinate, i.e. sends (n, i) to n - i, but returns n + 1 when i > n.
This is slightly different from what - does, which is to send differences-that-would-be-negative to 0.
Using an in-band error at all is a little bit of a hack, I chose it mostly out of frustrating previous experiences with using options in Coq.
Anyway, I am curious about how to prove flip_coordinate_bad_call_implies_error, which is forall n i, i > n -> flip_coordinate n i = S n.
I am especially curious about high-powered tactics that can handle induction on two natural numbers simultaneously if those exist.

From Coq Require Import Lia.

(* flip_coordinate flips a natural number coordinate i over
   in a dimension of length n.

   Dealing with options is annoying, so use n+1 as an in-band error value. *)
Fixpoint flip_coordinate_helper e n i :=
  match n with
  | O => match i with
          | O => O
          | _ => e
          end
  | S n' => match i with
            | O => n
            | S i' => (flip_coordinate_helper e n' i')
            end
  end
  .

Definition flip_coordinate n i := flip_coordinate_helper (1 + n) n i.

Example flip_coordinate_example : flip_coordinate 7 3 = 4.
Proof. now auto. Qed.

Example flip_coordinate_example_bad : flip_coordinate 7 10 = 8.
Proof. now auto. Qed.

Example flip_coordinate_example_borderline : flip_coordinate 7 7 = 0.
Proof. now auto. Qed.


Theorem flip_coordinate_zero : forall n, flip_coordinate n 0 = n.
Proof.
  intro n.
  now (induction n; intuition auto with *).
Qed.

Theorem flip_coordinate_bound : forall n, flip_coordinate n 0 <= S n.
Proof.
  intro n.
  now (induction n; intuition auto with *).
Qed.

Theorem successor_lt_iff_lt : forall n i, (S i > S n <-> i > n).
Proof. lia. Qed.

Theorem i_lt_n_case_analysis : forall n i, i > n <-> (i = S n \/ i > S n).
Proof. lia. Qed.

Theorem bad_call_lemma1 : forall n, flip_coordinate (S n) (S (S n)) = S (S n).
Proof.
  induction n.
  easy.
  unfold flip_coordinate in *.
Admitted.

Theorem flip_coordinate_bad_call_implies_error :
  forall n i, i > n -> flip_coordinate n i = S n.
intros n i.
induction i.
now intuition auto with *.
induction n.
now intuition auto with *.
intuition auto with *.
pose proof successor_lt_iff_lt n i.
rewrite H0 in H.
clear H0.
pose proof i_lt_n_case_analysis n i.
assert (i = S n \/ i > S n) by firstorder.
clear H0.
destruct H1.
rewrite H0. now pose proof bad_call_lemma1 n.
pose proof (IHi H0).
clear IHi.
Admitted.
```


You seem to be talking about "induction on two natural numbers simultaneously". This concept does not make sense, but nonetheless your theorems can be proven in Coq using standard techniques.
The reason why you are struggling to prove your theorems is that they are special cases of more general theorems that would actually be provable.
As a general rule, try stating your theorems to be proven by induction directly on the recursive definition flip_coordinate_helper, instead of on derived functions using that definition (like flip_coordinate).
Note that flip_coordinate_helper is defined by recursion on n. Therefore, theorems about it should in general be provable by induction on n. However, i also changes throughout the induction, so the induction will usually need to have i quantified in the inductive hypothesis. Further, the third variable, e, has nothing to do with the other two and should usually not be entangled to it. In your induction, it should simply be e.
Let's look at bad_call_lemma1. This lemma is overtly complex, and also a special case of a more general lemma about flip_coordinate_helper, which is the one you actually want to prove here. The more general lemma on flip_coordinate_helper is the following:
Theorem bad_call_lemma1' e n : flip_coordinate_helper e n (S n) = e.
Proof.
  induction n; simpl; easy.
Qed.

Theorem bad_call_lemma1 : forall n, flip_coordinate (S n) (S (S n)) = S (S n).
Proof.
  intros n. eapply bad_call_lemma1'.
Qed.

Notice that the actual induction is on n. Also notice how the lemma we prove by induction does not "entangle" e and n. The lemma proves that whatever is e, you get it at the end. If you instead specialize e to n+1 before doing the induction, this leads to cases that are impossible to prove, since the induction now requires that e is one smaller in the inductive hypothesis, but it is not.
A more interesting lemma is the helper lemma necessary to prove the final theorem:
Lemma flip_coordinate_bad_call_implies_error_e e n i :
 i > n -> flip_coordinate_helper e n i = e.
Proof.
  intros Hin.
  induction n in i,Hin|-*. (* the |-* syntax simply means to "revert i Hin; induction ...; intros i Hin" *)
  - simpl. destruct i. 1: lia. easy.
  - simpl. destruct i. 1: lia.
     rewrite IHn. 1: easy. lia.
Qed.

This theorem is proven by induction on n, with i quantified. This means that i can vary throughout the induction, which is crucially used to rewrite IHn with a different i than the one you started with. This is (part of) what is missing in your proof, since the way you set up your induction requires that i never changes throughout, which can't work.
Also again notice how we have e be simply an independent variable. Later, outside the induction, it is specialized to n+1. But that happens later, mirroring how flip_coordinate is defined later, as a special case of the more general recursive function.
So to summarize, the issue is setting up your induction, in particular finding the right induction hypothesis. This is, unfortunately, a very hard problem. It takes skill and a lot of practice. There are no "high-powered tactics" that can automate this problem for you, it requires you to figure out some deep facts about your functions and to express them back into logic.
